# how to send images from reactJS to Django rest framework

Tags: reactjs, django, typescript, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I have problem sending an image from reactJS to DRF3, my code is below, please help me.

DRF3 code

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer, FileField


class UploadSerializer(Serializer):
     """serialzer to upload files"""

    file_uploaded = FileField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ["file_uploaded"]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from .serializers import UploadSerializer


class UploadViewSet(ViewSet):
    """view to manage images"""

   serializer_class = UploadSerializer

   def list(self, request):
       """list images uploaded"""
       return Response("get api list")

   def create(self, request):
    try:
        file_uploaded = request.FILES.get("file_uploaded")
        f_s = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = f_s.save(file_uploaded.name, file_uploaded)
        image_url = f_s.url(filename)

        return Response({"data": f"{image_url}"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    except Exception as err:
        return Response(
            {"data": False, "msg": f"{err}"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        )
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UploadViewSet

app_name = "uploaded-images"

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "images", UploadViewSet.as_view({"post": "create"}), name="create-upload-images"
    )
]
```

here everythings working when I use postman, working well, but the problem is when send image through reactJS, my code is bellow

file send image with typescript

sendImage.tsx

```
import API from '../api-img' // my IP SERVER, working


export class UploadFiles {

    private resp: any

    uploadImg = async(file_upload:any) => {
        this.resp = await API.post(`upload/images`, file_upload, {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=--- 
                        WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'}
    })
    return this.resp
    
    }
 }
```

my component for send images

SendImage.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form'
import {Row, Col} from 'react-styled-flexboxgrid'
import DefaultImg from '../../form-basic/public/default.png'
import {UploadFiles} from '../../../../../../userImg'

type FormData = {
    photo: any
}

type userType = {
   user: string
   email: string
}

interface Iauth {
    authenticated: boolean
    currentUser: userType
}

const SendImg: React.FC<Iauth> = ({authenticated, currentUser}) => {
    let token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')
    let UploadImages = new UploadFiles()
    const {register, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm<FormData>({
       mode: 'onChange'
    })

const onSubmit = handleSubmit(({photo}) => {
   // this console show a File like this
   // FileList {0: File, length: 1}
   //   0: File {name: "black_friday.png", lastModified: 1605207093078, lastModifiedDate: 
   //Thu Nov 12 2020 15:51:33 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", 
   //size:   599515, …}
   //length: 1
   //__proto__: FileList
    console.info(photo)

    // method send Image
    UploadImages.uploadImg(photo)
        .then(resp => {
            console.info(resp.data)
        }).catch(err=>{
            console.error(err)
            // BUT WHEN SEND IMAGES IN HERE AND DISPLAY THIS ERROR
            // IN THE TAB NETWORK, RESPONSE
            // {"data":false,"msg":"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'"}

        })

     }

})

return(
   <form onSubmit={onSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" 
          name="photo" 
          ref={register({required: true})} 
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
   <button>send</button>
   </form>
 )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    authenticated: state.user.authenticated,
    currentUser: state.user
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Personal)
```

when send image through the reactJS, not working, I don't know why not send images, my server DRF3 recive data NONE.

please help me

thanks for all my friends. :)